# HTML: Is there anything wrong with using lots of <form> tags?

Tags: html

In many prototype scripting cases, it's easier to just stick every form item (such as an input or textarea) in its own form tag.  Is there anything wrong that could happen from having lots (like 1000) form tags in a page?

Comment: I guess only one form can be posted at a time, so If you want to access content in more than one form in your page, it will get complicated, if you just want data of one form at a time, then I think that should be fine

Comment: Why is this question down-voted? It looks perfectly legal.

Comment: Whenever some one down votes a post, please post the reason for it as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by ‘prototype scripting cases’? How are the forms being submitted?

If each form is its own action, eg. you have lots of separate product listings with different REST `action` URLs, then, yes, a separate form per line is appropriate.

If you're just using controls on their own for scripting, and have no intention of submitting them through the normal HTML form process, you don't need any `<form>` elements at all, just include them bare.

(Except in the specific case of radio buttons, which require a `<form>` for grouping.)

Answer (score 0):

Should not be a problem but why do that when you can just use one form. It will work even with 1000 forms but it would be stupid with over 50 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly wrong with it, but It would be a better idea to have them all in the same or fewer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, first off, have 1000 inputs on a single screen poses a different problem that should be addressed first.  That many controls will be completely unusable.

That being said, having each element in its own form will cause more overhead in processing your page.  You'll have to decide whether the impact of this is too large in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You will lose the info from other input elements when submitting any of these 1-input forms, since a form submission ONLY submits the values for input elements of that one form.

If you're OK with that in your prototype, not a big problem

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with this is the semantic process of what a form is. A form should only submit what the fields inside of it have. So, anything related to that "form" should have the proper fields with in it.

Technically, when using a form it'll take you to a new page, so, any of your values in any other form on that page will be lost. The only way around this is using javascript to ajaxily submit the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with using the HTML markup in the way you are wondering. The only thing you will want to worry about is the more control structues you add to your HTML the more text the web server needs to serve up. This will lengthen the amount of time it takes to get your code from the server to the users browser.